# descriptive statistics or summary statistics PySpark 3.0.1

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, statistics, describe

I have a spark df and need to get the basic descriptive statistics like in this example:
[image]

My spark version is 3.0.1 I have ran the following code:

```
df.describe().show()
```

But it only outputs the data, without any statistical summaries.

Comment: Please provide a minimal code that reproduces this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This will happen if your DataFrame is empty (I'm also using Spark 3.0.1).

Try this working example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand, randn

df = sqlContext.range(0, 10).withColumn('uniform', rand(seed=10)).withColumn('normal', randn(seed=27))
df.describe().show()
```

[image]

Now try with an empty DataFrame:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(([],))
df.describe().show()
```

[image]